# JDBC-Cancel/kill SQL transaction specifically for Vertica DB

Tags: jdbc, vertica

I'm using JDBC for performing DB CRUD operations. Is there a way to cancel/kill SQL transaction through JDBC.
**Statement.cancel()** is somehow not working.
Please provide your suggestion specific to Vertica DB.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `Statement.close()` to close?

Comment: No, but Statement.close() will release the resources so, will it have any effect on the query running on DB?

Comment: have posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well javadocs of `Statement.cancel()` method says below :

> /**
>        * Cancels this `Statement` object if both the DBMS and
>        * driver support aborting an SQL statement.
>        * This method can be used by one thread to cancel a statement that
>        * is being executed by another thread.
>        *
>        * @exception SQLException if a database access error occurs or
>        * this method is called on a closed `Statement`
>        * @exception SQLFeatureNotSupportedException if the JDBC driver does not support
>        * this method
>        */

```
void cancel() throws SQLException;
```

So for the above method to run successful, both DBMS and driver should support statement cancellation.

I've not used Vertica DB but a similar discussion had happened [here](https://github.com/serge-rider/dbeaver/issues/29) and it was told that vertica driver doesn't support statement cancellation.

You can think of connection close or thread interrupt as a workaround.

Hope this helps!